# C3D GeoTIFF not recognized by QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, civil3d

I had a DEM exported from C3D with MGA-56 coordinate system. When I import the DEM to QGIS, QGIS doesn't recognize the coordinate system. I set my project CRS at MGA-56.

[image]

Did I do something wrong?

This is a dropbox link. Let me know if this works
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zw28sug8wd6hm8d/61339%20Detail%20Plan-JCB-02.dwg?dl=0

This happens when I drag and drop to a new file in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: You probably didn't do anything wrong. Sometimes Civil 3D's Coordinate System Name isn't recognized by QGIS and vice versa. Also, MGA-56 comes in more than one Datum. Please post a link to your Civil 3D drawing.

Comment: I placed a dropbox link above. Thank you.

Comment: The linked file does not seem to load correctly in QGIS nor in online DWG viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Civil 3D click the ellipsis at "Export coordinate zone" and verify MGA-56 coordinate system before hitting OK. I don't know why, but this step seems to be necessary.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I thank you for your solution @Pointdump. Still, QGIS doesn't recognize MGA-56 from C3D. I am now thinking this is more of a C3D problem than a QGIS one. Maybe C3D was not able to "attach" the coordinate system into the GeoTIFF file?

Comment: It works for me. Civil 3D uses EPSG:28356 for its definition of MGA-56. I'm able to export a GeoTiff and when I drag-n-drop it into QGIS it is recognized as EPSG:28356. I re-tested just now with your drawing and it works.

Comment: When I dragged and dropped, this happens. (I updated my question above. It seems I can't drop a screenshot in the comments)

Comment: And it worked for the second time @Pointdump. Thank you for your time and THE BIG HELP!